# Slicing python dataframe with isin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am trying something I think is simple, however I keep getting errors and I don't know why.

I am trying to set a value in a new column for `df2`. If value is column from `df2` matches any value from `df1` "col", then write "result", otherwise "no result".

```
#Create a series from df column 
series_from_df = df1['Col']
df2['new_col'] = 'result' if df2['Col1'].isin(series_from_df) else 'Not result'
```

The above gets me an error:

> (<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('The truth value of a Series is
> ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'),
> <traceback object at 0x7f9081a28f80>)

Then I try the below adding the square brakes for series_from_df

```
#Create a series from df column 
series_from_df = df1['Col']
df2['new_col'] = 'result' if df2['Col1'].isin([series_from_df]) else 'Not result'
```

I get the same error than before.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df2['Col1'].isin(df1['Col1'])` is a boolean Series, but you're trying to use it as a condition in `if`, which is expecting a truth-value. You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead where the Series created by the `isin` is used as the condition:

```
df2['new_col'] = np.where(df2['Col1'].isin(df1['Col1']), 'result', 'Not result')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `map` to replace boolean values:

```
df2['new_col'] = \
    df2['Col1'].isin(df1['Col']).replace({True: 'result', False: 'Not Result'})
print(df2)

# Output
   Col1     new_col
0     1      result
1     2      result
2     3  Not Result
3     4      result
4     5      result
```

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': [1, 2, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

Comment: Many thanks @Corralien this solution works, however enkes provide an explanation of what I was doing wrong and his solution also works. Many thanks for your quick response.